# Using a Tokenizer (strtok) to parse a string. How can I get the second token of the string?

Tags: php

I want to grab the last name or second word of this variable

```
$name = 'Sandra Bullok';
$first_token  = strtok($name, ' ');
echo $first_token;
```

Will output "Sandra"

How can I output "Bullok"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$name = 'Sandra Bullok';
$parts = explode(' ', $name);
echo $parts[0]; // 'Sandra'
echo $parts[1]; // 'Bullok'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

If You want to do this with strtok():

```
$name = 'Sandra Bullok';
$first_token  = strtok($name, ' ');
$second_token = strtok(' ');
echo $first_token; // 'Sandra'
echo $second_token; // 'Bullok'
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
list($first, $last) = explode(' ', $name);
```

You can do some additional checking to see if how many there are as maybe there is a first, middle and last name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `strtok`, you should do something like this:

```
$name = 'Sandra Bullok';
$token = strtok($name, ' ');

while ($token !== FALSE) { // enter all possible values
    echo $token . ' ';
    $token = strtok(' ');
}
```

[strtok reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)